# Is there a way to listen for changes in an Microsoft SQL database table using Java and JDBC?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have an application connected to a database on a Microsoft SQL Server, I need to listen to any changes (create and update mainly) done on one of the tables and trigger an action in java in that application. 
Is there any way to do so?

Comment: A way would be to have triggers on your data tables which would populate other tables on change. Your application would frequently poll these tables and remove the rows it handles. I feel like this is old-fashioned and there might be more integrated ways to do this though.

Comment: Basically, there is no other way than to poll the DB table periodically. If possible, you should try to get the actor responsible for updating the table to invoke the Java code directly through an API of some sort; this would be simpler and faster. Without knowing more about the context or your _actual problem_, it's hard to give good advice.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how quickly you need to react to the change on the table and what access you have on the database. 
If you can tolerate couple of seconds delay I would query (every couple of seconds) table information from system tables for last updated information. This will only work if you have access to system tables.

Try googling "microsoft sql table get last updated information", there are quite a few examples which might help your particular case.

Comment: the idea is to retrieve the row data from the DB as soon as it's inserted, there might be multiple entries.